# Statistics with probable outcomes

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose an instructor ha a class with 14 freshmen, 15 sophmores, 8 juniors, and 10 seniors. Say 8 names will be drawn from a hot to go on a trip. How many different draws of 8 names are there overall? How many different draws of 8 names would contain only juniors? How many different draws of 8 names would contain exactly 4 juniors and 4 seniors?

May you please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about binomial coefficients?
Their definition is ${n}\choose{k}$ = $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$ and their interpretation is that if you have $n$ elements and you randomly draw $k$ of them, there is exactly ${n}\choose{k}$ possibilities how to do it. This answers your first question.

The second question is really simple - there is exactly one possible draw. If you do not see it, just think of it.

I hope that the interpretation of binomial coefficient helped you to easily answer the third question. You choose 4 people of 8 and then independently choose another 4 people of 10. Are you able to count, how many different draws can do it?